# Select all same column based on a specific column value php pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table like below

```
ID     Status
1      InActive
2      Active
3      Active
4      InActive
5      Active
```

I want to select ID 2 then get the status of ID 2 then based on that status I want to select all the remaining ID with the same Status.

I was not able to create a simple demo because I cant think of a way how to select.

Expected:
`Get ID 2,3,5` because they all have active status

Currently working on the problem at hand

Base select:

`Select * from table where id = 2`

I want to know what to add to this query to be able to select the other 2 row that share same status with the id 2

Comment: `select id where status ="Active"`

Comment: this will give only 1 result because ID is specified to be 2

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Close, but we don't necessarily know what the status for `ID=2` is.  To find that, we'd have to do some sort of query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using a subquery to find the ID 2 status:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Status = (SELECT Status FROM yourTable WHERE ID = 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use **JOIN** for your result.

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename` AS t1
JOIN `tablename` AS t2 ON t1.Status = t2.Status where t1.ID = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT `ID` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `Status` = (SELECT `Status` FROM `table` WHERE `ID` = 2)
```